# Como sobrepor a animação de carregar dentro de uma div?

Tags: html5, css3, css-animations

tudo bem com vocês? Estou criando um formulário onde ao clicar em algum dos botões gostaria que surgisse uma animação de carregar. Porém ao clicar ele sobrepõem a div no qual está inserido o formulário.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para deixar a animação embaixo dos botões quando clicado.

Segue o código que estou desenvolvendo.

```
    .sessao00{
        padding-left: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 335px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #8998d3a2;
    }



.carregar-animacao {
        animation: is-rotating 1s infinite;
        border: 6px solid #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Peço desculpas se caso estiver bem desajeitado o código, sou bem iniciante.

Answer (score -2):

Na próxima pergunta lembre-se de colocar seu **código completo**, você não mandou seu **HTML**.

## Possível solução

Basta alterar o texto dentro do seu botão usando JS quando você clicar nele, e criar uma condição para que o botão retorne com seu texto original.

Dê uma olhada no fiddle a seguir:

https://jsfiddle.net/15ebrLnc/